# Animate CC advances to the next frame with gotoAndStop commented out?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, jquery-animate

I'm writing this code that tests your reaction time and then advances to the next frame. It shows a box and then time the difference between when the box appeared and when the use presses [A]. Heer is my code

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

stop();
    var canPress = false;
    var startClock:Timer = new Timer(4000+Math.random()*6000, 1);
    grbox.y = -500;
    startClock.start();
    var startTime:int = 0;

function displayBox(evt:Event):void{
    canPress = true;
    grbox.y = 143;
    var startTime:int = getTimer();
}

function Tpressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.A){
        if(canPress==true){
        var endTime:int = getTimer();
        score1 = endTime-startTime;

        if(score2<0){
            //gotoAndStop(3);
        }
        else{
            //gotoAndStop(4);
        }
   }
   }

}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, Tpressed);
startClock.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, displayBox);
```

For some reason if I just spam the [A] button it will advance to the next frame. Why is this happening?!?! My 'gotoAndStop(4);' command is commented out so it should do *anything*, yet it is.

EDIT: Here is my .fla file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxtLreFIVnSWR2VPSGdSaHZGaVk
RAW CODE: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GRZIaKAdRNu3z3aPjjXNcgqMl2BhR-ZBT6gU7OeSbWQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's weird. You don't have a listener anywhere else? Like in the square movie clip?

Comment: I don't think so, the only two listeners I have are on my code. I can try to upload my project file if that helps?

Comment: Does it happen if you press any other button? Or just A?

Comment: It happens only when I press [A].
I don't think getTimer is a custom function. I uploaded my code to Gdrive on the main post.

Comment: I don't seem to have the option to save as an actionscript file. Only .xfl or .fla.
I've uploaded the raw code to a google doc. Horizontal lines indicate new frames. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GRZIaKAdRNu3z3aPjjXNcgqMl2BhR-ZBT6gU7OeSbWQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try commenting this out `//gotoAndStop(Math.round(Math.random()+2))` and tell me what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one of your frames you added an event listener for key presses to the stage. That's probably where your problem is at. So when you press any key, it calls the `pressed` function as well as the `Tpressed` function. And since the key that is being checked for in each function is "A", both functions execute their `if` blocks. And both `if` blocks call a `gotoAndStop` method.

Without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish in the big picture, this problem could be fixed by removing the event listener for the `pressed` function when you leave that frame.

Could look like:

```
function pressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.A){
        gotoAndStop(Math.round(Math.random()+2));
        // remove the event listener since we are leaving this frame and you apparently only want this function to work on this frame
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressed); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will edit my code and get back soon.

Again, thank you so much.